Trying to resolve view with tag 105 which doesn't exist

Getting this error every time I click on  TextInput field in android.
When I put it in component with just view in App.tsx it works goor, but I am using Tab.Navigator and when I navigate to screen with TextInput components I get previously mentioned error.
Code example where it works properly:
`
const App = () => {
 const [text, setText] = useState('');

 return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    value={text}
    onChangeText={setText}
    placeholder="Type here..."
  />
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    value={text}
    onChangeText={setText}
    placeholder="Type here..."
  />
  <ProfileOverviewScreen />
</View>
);
 };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
},
  input: {
  height: 40,
  borderColor: 'gray',
  borderWidth: 1,
  width: '80%',
  paddingHorizontal: 10,
},
});

export default App;

Code example where it is not working:
NavBarComponent:
`
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
export function NavBar() {
return (
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Feed"
  activeColor="powderblue"
  barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'steelblue' }}
  key={'key'}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Feed"
    component={Feed}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    key={'key2'}
    name="Activities"
    component={Activities}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Activities',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="run" color={color} size={26} />
      ),
    }}
  ></Tab.Screen>
  <Tab.Screen
    key={'key3'}
    name="Profile"
    component={ProfileStack}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={26} />
      ),
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
 );
}``

ProfileComponent:
` export function ProfileStack() {
  return (

<ProfileScreen></ProfileScreen>
);
}`

ProfileScreen :
`
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'flex-start',
},
boxLabel: {
backgroundColor: 'rgba(22, 58, 89, 0.8)',
color: 'white',
flex: 1,
borderRadius: 25,
paddingTop: 20,
height: screenHeight - 20,
width: screenWidth - 30,
margin: 5,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'flex-start',
},
inputField: {
height: 40,
borderColor: 'powderblue',
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius: 20,
borderStyle: 'solid',
width: 150,
padding: 5,
justifyContent: 'flex-end',
fontSize: 18,
color: 'powderblue',
},
input: {
height: 40,
borderColor: 'gray',
borderWidth: 1,
width: '80%',
paddingHorizontal: 10,
,
 textLabel: { padding: 5, color: 'powderblue', fontSize: 20 },
inputGroup: {
display: 'flex',
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
padding: 5,
},
});

const displayValue = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export function ProfileOverviewScreen() {
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [secondName, setSecondName] = useState('');
const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
const [weight, setWeight] = useState(0);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
const [login, setLogin] = useState(true);
const [token, setToken] = useState<JWTPayload>(initialJWTPalyload);
const [stpsGoal, setStepsGoal] = useState(1000);

const [text, setText] = useState('');

async function getUser() {
const token = await decodeToken();
const jwtToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://192.168.100.9:8080/api/users/' + token.jti,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
  },
};
console.log('idd ' + jwtToken + 'teekst');
console.log(config.url);
try {
  await axios(config).then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data);
    setUsername(resp.data.username);
    setFirstName(resp.data.firstName);
    setSecondName(resp.data.secondName);
    setStepsGoal(resp.data.stepsgoal);
    setWeight(resp.data.weight);
    setHeight(resp.data.height);
    setAge(resp.data.age);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
 }

useEffect(() => {
getUser();
}, [login]);

function handleClikc(tetx: any) {
console.log(tetx);
}

return (
  <LinearGradient
  colors={['steelblue', 'powderblue', 'skyblue']}
  style={styles.container}
>
  <View style={styles.boxLabel}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      value={text}
      onChangeText={setText}
      placeholder="Type here..."
    />
    <View
      style={{
        height: 130,
        width: 130,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(70,130,180, 0.5)',
        borderRadius: 100,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="account"
          color={'powderblue'}
          size={30}
        />{' '}
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ color: 'powderblue', fontSize: 20 }}>{username}</Text>
    </View>

  
  </View>
</LinearGradient>
);
}

`
